# gps con NETWORK_PROVIDER

Tags: android, gps

Estoy intentando posicionar mi ubicación en una aplicación android que estoy desarrollando. Estuve leyendo por internet que hay 3 tipos de providers y leí sus diferencias por lo que al final me decanté por NETWORK_PROVIDER pero no acabo de entender si es necesario tener el gps activado para que funcione con la red.

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendio puedes utilizar la geolocalizacion por IP que seria por NETWORK_PROVIDER  y esto lo harías sin nesecidad del GPS , tambien puedes usar la forma GSM que seria por medio de la ubicacion fisica en red que nose como se pueda hacer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es una interesante pregunta, c**uando usas como proveedor `NETWORK_PROVIDER` , tu dispositivo no necesita tener habilitado el `GPS`. Puedes tener habilitados los dos proveedores o alguno de ellos.**

Existen diferencias importantes que considero son importantes a comentar:

- Si tus servicios de geo-localización son determinados por la red WiFi o móvil el consumo de batería es bajo, pero la exactitud de la posición no es tan confiable.
- En cambio si tus servicios de geo-localización son determinados por el GPS, el consumo de batería es mayor comparado con el proveedor de red, pero la exactitud de la posición es mucho mejor.

Como comento, puedes usar alguno o ambos proveedores, incluso puedes determinar individualmente la disponibilidad de alguno:

```
    private static boolean disponiblepGPS, disponibleRED;
    private static LocationManager locManager;
    private static String provider;

   //Determina si el NETWORK_PROVIDER esta disponible:
        try {
            disponibleRED = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Error obteniendo NETWORK_PROVIDER.");
        }


     //Determina si el GPS_PROVIDER esta disponible:
        try {
            disponiblepGPS = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Error obteniendo GPS_PROVIDER.");
        }
```

Actualmente la mayoría de los dispositivos pueden configurar que proveedores usar para obtener la geo-localización. Para obtener con mayor exactitud se utilizan los dos proveedores A), para usar únicamente la red, con un consumo bajo de energía la red B) o se puede únicamente usar el GPS C).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ok, pero el problema es que en la aplicación que estoy desarrollando solo se activa la red cuando activo el gps. ¿Por qué puede ser si con NETWORK_PROVIDER no se necesita gps?

Comment: @adamista, seguramente es tu código, puedes habilitar el proveedor programaticamente, sería bueno agregaras tu código donde realizas esta acción.

Comment: @adamista agregué más información, si tu configuración soporta cualquiera de los dos proveedores, por código puedes usar cualquiera o ambos,.saludos.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias :D